# Bookmarklet - Go to the Top level Domain without the subdomain

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

How do I get this bookmarklet to take me from `abc.example.com` to `example.com` ?

I tried the following:

```
javascript:location.pathname%20=%20"";%20void%200
```

But it takes me to the same sub-domain (`abc.example.com`) and not `example.com`.

Comment: If you still need it, you may use something like this: `javascript:location.href=location.protocol+%22//%22+%22www%22+%22.%22+(location.host.split(%22.%22).length==3?location.host.split(%22.%22).slice(1,location.host.split(%22.%22).length).join(%22.%22):location.host)+location.pathname+location.search;` (found the orginal solution [here](http://www.evanconkle.com/2012/03/switch-domain-bookmarklet/))

Answer (score 2):

[`location.pathname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils.pathname) returns only the parts of the URL after the domain.

You might have more luck with [`location.hostname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils.hostname), which returns the domain of the URL.

Here's a javascript example that returns the last two parts of the hostname (split by "."):

```
var loc = window.location;

var parts = loc.hostname.split('.').reverse();
if (parts.length > 2) {
    parts.length = 2;
}

var newloc = parts.reverse().join('.');

console.log(loc + " > " + newloc);
```

This outputs `example.com` from `subdomain.example.com`.

[Try it here (jsfiddle).](http://jsfiddle.net/AWuWq/)
In that example, I'm hardcoding the hostname rather than using `window.location.hostname`.